# Склонение фамилии "Воробей"

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение, ономастика

Имеется мужская фамилия "Воробей".
Как правильно будет в дательном падеже: *Вороб**ью*** или *Вороб**ею***?
И на чем основывается вывод, или, может, оба варианта правильные?

Answer (score 1):

Этот вопрос задавали Справочной Грамоты.ру:

**[Вопрос № 272978](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%20272978)**

(Обратите внимание на предпочтения Справки.)

*В дательном падеже фамилия Воробей? Воробью или Воробей?*

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

*Склоняется только мужская фамилия. В дательном падеже возможно: Воробью и Воробею. Предпочтительно склонять без выпадения гласного (т. е. Воробею), поскольку фамилии выполняют в том числе юридическую функцию.*

Comment: Здесь Грамота поясняет свой выбор: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=283979

Comment: Да, спасибо. Хотя по ссылке - то же, но на большем количестве примеров. А выбор формы всегда за носителем, особенно "страдают" ударения. ГУлая (Инна) - ГулАя, Ирину РОзанову превратили в РозАнову, МаксИменко спорят с МаксимЕнко, а у нас журналист МЯсников зверел при обзывании его МясникОвым...

Answer (score 1):

Не-не, правильно — *Воробью*.
На той же ["Грамоте"](http://www.gramota.ru/class/istiny/istiny_8_familii/#:%7E:text=%D0%92%D1%81%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B8%2C%20%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0,%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B8%2C%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%81%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8.):

> Примечание 2. Отдельно необходимо сказать о фамилиях, оканчивающихся на согласный *й*. Если ему предшествует гласный *и* (реже — *о*), фамилия может склоняться двояко. Такие фамилии, как *Топчий, Побожий, Бокий, Рудой*,  можно воспринять как имеющие окончания *-ий, -ой* и склонять как прилагательные (*Топчего, Топчему*, в женском роде *Топчая, Топчей*), а можно — как имеющие нулевое окончание со склонением по образцу существительных (*Топчия, Топчию*, в женском роде неизменяемая форма *Топчий*).
> Если согласному *й* на конце фамилии предшествует любой другой гласный, фамилия подчиняется **общим правилам** (*Игорю Шахраю, Николаю Аджубею*, но *Инне Шахрай, Александре Аджубей*).

Воробей — Воробью ([Джеку Воробью](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%94%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%20%D0%92%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8C%D1%8E%22&ei=61NIY5PDD9OHwPAPhYCvUA&ved=0ahUKEwjT5IGU5t36AhXTAxAIHQXACwoQ4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=%22%D0%94%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%20%D0%92%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8C%D1%8E%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBggAEAUQHjIGCAAQBRAeMgYIABAFEB46CggAEEcQ1gQQsAM6DQgAEOQCENYEELADGAE6CggAEAgQBxAeEA86BwgAEIAEEA06BggAEB4QDToICAAQHhANEAo6CggAEB4QDxANEAo6CAgAEB4QDxANOgUIABCiBEoECE0YAUoECEEYAEoECEYYAVCkD1irIWCgOGgBcAF4AIABZYgBnASSAQM1LjGYAQCgAQHIAQ3AAQHaAQYIARABGAk&sclient=gws-wiz) — 15000, [Джеку Воробею](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%94%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%20%D0%92%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%8E%22&nfpr=1&filter=0&biw=1366&bih=657&dpr=1) — 10); Соловей — Соловью (Валерию Соловью — 761, Валерию Соловею — 7).

Ещё — по общим правилам (этих слов совсем немного): Чирей — Чирью, Улей — Улью, Муравей — Муравью, Репей — Репью, Ручей — Ручью, Соловей — Соловью.

Comment: Про "Соловей" Грамота то же самое говорит, но уже обоснование даёт: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=283979

Comment: *Второй вариант предпочтителен (чтобы отделить фамилию от омонимичного нарицательного существительного)*... Не понимаю такой странной рекомендации. А что же делать людям с фамилиями Жук, Комар, Ворон, Шелест, Боб, Лисица, Куница, Окунь?.. Как же им надо "испоперекрутиться", чтобы отделиться от нарицательного существительного? Для них такой лазейки нет.

Comment: Например: *Нет Соловья.* Это можно сказать по приколу, кто-то может и засмеяться. На ваш вопрос отвечает Розенталь: http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/57.htm — §151, пункт 4.

Comment: Удивительное дело! Нет Жука, нет Окуня, нет Комара — это нормально, а нет Соловья — смешно?

Comment: Да то же самое. Особенно если говорили о чём-то, что связано с этими животными.

Comment: Но "Соловья" смешнее, потому что это может быть кличкой из-за чего-то негативного (например, недостаточной компетенции, тупости, как мне кажется). С "Окунь" тоже такое (*тупой, как окунь*), но меньше, потому что не особо используется как кличка.

Answer (score 0):

"Воробею" - звучит не по-русски. Надо использовать только "Воробью", если это фамилия мужчины. Для примера: [дать] Джеку Воробью. Если это женщина, то фамилия не склоняется, то есть: [кто] Елена Воробей, [кому] Елене Воробей.

Comment: У Джека "Воробей" – прозвище, а не фамилия. :)

Comment: С чего вы взяли, что мы об одном Джеке говорим.

Comment: Ни с чего не взяла. Вот вы сказали – и я теперь понимаю, что мы говорим о разных Джеках: я о том, у которого "Джек" – прозвище, а вы о тех, у которых это фамилия. А сослаться на какой-нибудь авторитетный источник можете в обоснование своего ответа?

Comment: А какой ещё есть Джек Воробей?

Comment: @Алёнушка Не думаю, что это может быть фамилией Джека, потому что имя не русское, а фамилия русская (перевод "Sparrow").

Comment: В наше время не могут назвать ребенка Джеком, фамилия отца которого - Воробей? Совершенно не важно, где русское имя, а где нет. В наше время многие называют детей иностранными именами, при этом они имеют русские фамилии.

Comment: Это английское имя, и у него есть русские варианты. *В наше время многие называют детей иностранными именами* — не сталкивался. Если такое у кого-то в паспорте (во что трудно поверить), то это прикол, потому что это не может быть просто совпадением.